# AngularJS 1.x: How to highlight active menu item one a time (not multiples)?

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, selecteditem

it may seem trivial, but how to **select one at a time**?

When I click other items, previous item should **turn false** and only **current item** should be *selected*.
Here is the **working plnkr**: https://plnkr.co/edit/cHDwdO3ioZLf0NyfOyEr?p=preview Thanks.

```
<section ng-controller="DemoController">
<div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="selectItem(item)">

  <span ng-class="{'active' : item.selected }">{{item.name}}</span>

</div>
```

```
$scope.list = [
{
  name: 'Item 1',
  selected: true
},
{
  name: 'Item 2',
  selected: false
},
{
  name: 'Item 3',
  selected: false
}];


$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
  item.selected = !item.selected;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace This function

```
$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
    angular.forEach($scope.list,function(value){
      if(value.name==item.name){
        value.selected = true;
      } else {
        value.selected = false;
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Fantastic! I So straightforward! Thank you!